# Grep 'binary file matches'. How to get normal grep output?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I've got a grep script that searches through a directory recursively.

```
grep -n -R -e 'search term' -e 'second search term' ./
```

However the results I get are the following. Notice there are found matches in JPGs but no actual result.

```
Binary file ./jpg/00015928.jpg matches
Binary file ./jpg/00015296.jpg matches
Binary file ./jpg/00020072.jpg matches
```

Is there any way to see the result in the output like a normal grep search?

Comment: What output do you expect from grep?

Answer (score 361, accepted):

Try:

```
grep --text
```

or

```
grep -a
```

for short. This is equivalent to `--binary-files=text` and it should show the matches in binary files.

Comment: Note that you may need this flag in case your input file is indeed text file but it contains e.g. some random binary bytes in the middle because the data is corrupted or the "binary content" *heuristics* fails otherwise. The intent to need to specify this flag is to avoid outputting raw binary content to output accidentally if you `grep` a binary file by mistake. Traditionally outputting binary content to terminal could mess the whole terminal and require resetting the terminal to continue but that shouldn't happen with modern UTF-8 based systems.

Comment: `-a, --text
              Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the --binary-files=text option.`